# Add link attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to shorten text and add "Read More" with its link.

Sample html code:

```
<article id="post-58" class="post-58 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-2">

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/archives/58" rel="bookmark">
                Title Here
            </a>
        </h2>
    </header>
    <!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
<article id="post-57" class="post-57 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-2">

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/archives/57" rel="bookmark">
                Title Here
            </a>
        </h2>
    </header>
    <!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
        <p>Content text here</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

I want to change the length of the Entry Content to 175 characters and add "Reader More" whose link needs to be pulled from `href` attribute under "entry-title" class.

I tried the following script:

```
$("body.blog .entry-content").text(function(index, currentText) {
     return currentText.substr(0, 175)+'...';
     $(this).append('<a class="readmore">Read More</a>');
     var lnk = $(this).parent('article').children('.entry-header a').attr('href'); 
     $('a.readmore', this).attr('href', lnk);
});
```

The content will be shortened but it does not add "Read More"...

How can I correct the script?

Thanks.

Comment: you are returning right away.

Comment: @Daniel. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line

```
return currentText.substr(0, 175)+'...';
```

to the bottom of the function. Return ends the execution of the function, and the rest of your code is not running past that.

Your function then becomes:

```
$("body.blog .entry-content").text(function(index, currentText) {
     $(this).append('<a class="readmore">Read More</a>');
     var lnk = $(this).parent('article').children('.entry-header a').attr('href'); 
     $('a.readmore', this).attr('href', lnk);
     return currentText.substr(0, 175)+'...';
});
```